# In Electron app, after using webpack/electron-builder to package, require third-party module in worker_threads prompts MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, electron-builder

> ENV:

- Electron: v11.0.3
- Node: v14.15.1
- OS: win10 2020 x64

> package.json - build

```
"build":{
  "productName": "myapp",
  "directories": {
    "output": "build"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/electron/**/*"
  ]
}
```

> Webpack.json

```
{
    entry: {
      main: path.join(__dirname, '../src/main/index.js')
    },
    externals: [
      ...Object.keys(dependencies || {})
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
          test: /\.node$/,
          use: 'node-loader'
        }
      ]
    },
    node: {
      __dirname: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
      __filename: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
      path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist/electron')
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ExternalsPlugin("commonjs", ["node-hid"])
    ],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.node']
    },
    target: 'electron-main'
  }
```

> index.js

```
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');
const worker = new Worker(`const HID = require("node-hid");console.log("hello");`, { eval:true });
worker.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('worker error:',err);
});
```

The above code can output "hello" normally when running in the development environment, but when I run it after packaging it will output the following error:

```
worker error:
{code: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", requireStack: ["C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\myapp\[worker eval]"]}
```

Should I use `asarUnpack` related configuration?

Comment: it would be helpful if you could add your webpack and electron-builder configuration to your question

Comment: @Rhayene Thank you for your advice, I've added these configurations

Comment: I played around a bit - `worker_threads` itself worked fine after build. But I have run into the same error when running your sample without installing `node-hid` as dependency. It worked after build after installing `node-hid` as dependency (not dev-dependency). Although I got a `Segmentation fault` after closing the window - which is weird. You may want to check whether you have forgotten to install `node-hid` before continuing with your search.

Comment: however I did not build it with webpack - just with the default electron-builder config. if you installed `node-hid` it may be helpful to isolate your worker code to a fresh electron app and build it only with electron-builder to check if it works then. If yes, webpack may do something you don't want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used asarUnpack to solve this problem:

> index.js

```
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');
const worker = new Worker(`
    const path = require("path");
    function dynamicallyRequire(moduleName) {
        let modulePath = getNodeModulesPath(moduleName);
        let module = require(modulePath);
        return module;
    }
    function getNodeModulesPath(moduleName) {
        return workerData.env === 'development' ? moduleName : path.join(process.cwd(), 'resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\node_modules\\' + moduleName);
    }
    const HID = dynamicallyRequire("node-hid");
    console.log("hello");
`, { eval:true, workerData: { env: process.env.NODE_ENV }});
worker.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('worker error:',err);
});
```

> package.json --> build --> asarUnpack

```
"asarUnpack": [
  "./node_modules/node-hid/**/*",
  "./node_modules/node-addon-api/**/*",
  "./node_modules/bindings/**/*",
  "./node_modules/file-uri-to-path/**/*"
]
```

It is worth mentioning that the dependencies of node-hid also need to be included, such as `bindings`, `node-addon-api`, `file-uri-to-path`